# Sum of TextEditingControllers

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to get the sum of multiple `TextEditingController` via this function .

```
  void _CalculTotal() {
double total = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < widget.controllers.length; j++) {
  //print(widget.controllers[i].text);
  total = double.parse(widget.controllers[j].text);

  print(total);
}
```

}

I'm getting this error :

```
Invalid double
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
total = double.parse(widget.controllers[j].text);
```

with

```
total += double.tryParse(widget.controllers[j].text) ?? 0;
```

Problem 1: Instead of adding values to `total` you are setting them.

Problem 2: You have to make sure that the entered text can be parsed to double value. So, using tryParse will parse it to double if possible or just add 0 for that entry.

And also you are printing the `total` in every iteration. Better to do it after the loop. So your final code will look something like this:

```
void _CalculTotal() {
  double total = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < widget.controllers.length; j++) {
    //print(widget.controllers[i].text);
    total += double.tryParse(widget.controllers[j].text) ?? 0;
  }
  print(total);
}
```

Comment: This implementation kinda works. Let's say I write the number 36 in a text field. Using the above method in _onChanged_ parameter I get 3 + 36 = 39.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where exactly you're using it and what output you want?